# Попытка добавить число в переменную через функцию

Tags: python, функции

возникла проблема - я пытаюсь добавить число в глобальную переменную с помощью функции:

```
s = 0

def changes(arg1, arg2):
    arg1 += arg2

changes(s, 10)

print(s)
```

Ожидаемый вывод: 10

Вывод: 0

Comment: Это не добавляет число в глобальную переменную. Вам нужно перечитать главу о функциях.

Comment: как ни странно, но вывод абсолютно верный. У Вас явно были ошибочные ожидания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам надо использовать принимать один аргумент и использовать `global`

```
s = 0

def changes(arg1):
    global s
    s += arg1

changes(10)

print(s)
```

либо добавить `return`

```
s = 0

def changes(arg1, arg2):
    arg1 += arg2
    return arg1

s = changes(s, 10)

print(s)
```

Comment: Второй способ подходит, так как функция в моём случае должна будет принимать порядком больше аргументов.

Comment: @EngarDian Второй способ и более правильный, global лучше не использовать

Answer (score 1):

как вариант:

```
s = 0

def changes(arg1, arg2):
    s = arg1
    s += arg2
    return s

s = changes(s, 10)

print(s)
```